# Photoshop CC: how to break up subpaths?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, cc-2014

I can't figure out how to break a path's subpaths into separate, individual paths in Photoshop CC.  Everything I find online suggests there is an Object menu (?) but I'm either too stupid to locate it, or it's not in Photoshop CC.  I can't locate the information in Adobe's online documentation either.  Is this not possible in CC?

Comment: The Object menu is in Illustrator, not Photoshop. Can you explain what "subpaths" are??? Photoshop doesn't really create subpaths for paths. I think you need to describe in much more detail what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Select the subpath with Path selection tool and `Ctrl+J` or `Cmd+J`. That will make a copy of the shape into its own layer.

Comment: Now that I have some more time. Photoshop does call some paths `"Subpaths"`, although it could be argued that they're actually not. When you make multiple `Paths` into one path layer in the `Paths panel`, _every_ separate path is considered to be a subpath. If you make 2 paths, both of them are `Subpaths`. It doesn't make much sense, but that's how it is.` --- This is not the case, if you are adding paths to a `Shape layer`. Then it's all just one `Shape layer` with multiple paths.

Comment: If I got it right, try to select a point and Ctrl+X. It is deleted without creating a path connecting her nearest neighbours. So you can divide a path in two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photoshop doesn't have an equivalent to the Scissor tool in Illustrator or InDesign. To cut a path, add an anchor point on each side of the point where you want to cut, then delete the original anchor point.

The Path Selection Tool (black arrow) and Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) allow you to select individual paths in a vector layer, which you can then cut and paste onto a different layer.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use the Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd>) to select the points I wanted to break the path on, and then delete them.

I like the predictability of it: I know exactly which points will be deleted and where exactly the path will get broken up.

Answer (score 0):

Just select a point with white arrow and press *delete.*